# How can one make an ESP8266 connect to WPA2-Enterprise using PEAP instead of EAP-TTLS?

Tags: arduino, esp8266, arduino-esp8266, esp8266wifi

I want to connect an ESP8266 to a WPA2-Enterprise Wifi. When debugging, I see it trying to connect using EAP-TTLS and MSCHAPv2, but it needs to connect using PEAP and MSCHAPv2 (or EAP-TTLS and PAP). From what I have found, PEAP and MSCHAPv2 are supported by the ESP, but I can not figure out how to make it use those.

This is the code I'm using to connect:

```
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  wifi_set_opmode(STATION_MODE);
  struct station_config wifi_config;
  
  
  memset(&wifi_config, 0, sizeof(wifi_config));
  strcpy((char*)wifi_config.ssid, ssid);
  strcpy((char*)wifi_config.password, password);

  wifi_station_set_config(&wifi_config);
  wifi_set_macaddr(STATION_IF,target_esp_mac);
  

  wifi_station_set_wpa2_enterprise_auth(1);

  wifi_station_clear_cert_key();
  wifi_station_clear_enterprise_ca_cert();
  wifi_station_clear_enterprise_identity();
  wifi_station_clear_enterprise_username();
  wifi_station_clear_enterprise_password();
  wifi_station_clear_enterprise_new_password();
  
  wifi_station_set_enterprise_identity((uint8*)identity, strlen(identity));
  wifi_station_set_enterprise_username((uint8*)username, strlen(username));
  wifi_station_set_enterprise_password((uint8*)password, strlen(password));

  
  wifi_station_connect();  
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN,LOW);
    delay(500);
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN,HIGH);
  }
```